# Repetition at last instance of file read

Tags: c

```
int k;
char string[100];
    for(k = 0; k < MAX_STATIONS; k++){
        fgets(string,100,fp);
        printf("%s", string);
    }
```

So I've got my sniped of code here, and when I try to print the text from the file, the last line is either repeated maybe 10 times.

```
195     11.00  2013 11 02 15 32   49.76668  234.97289    30
196     11.40  2013 11 02 15 32   49.70103  235.04120    30
197      7.30  2013 11 02 15 32   48.52185  236.57961     5
199     10.00  2013 11 02 15 32   48.39511  236.69492     5
200      8.50  2013 11 02 15 32   48.48800  236.67270     5  200      8.50  2013 11 02     15 32   48.48800  236.67270     5  200      8.50  2013 11 02 15 32   48.48800  236.67270     5  200      8.50  2013 11 02 15 32   48.48800  236.67270     5  200      8.50  2013 11 02 15 32   48.48800  236.67270     5
```

That is my output, any help would be much appreciated. Also, I'd like a bit of clarification, what do we do with the middle part of fgets(string,100,fp) (100 in this case).

Thanks

EDIT: I seem to have solved the problem by adding

```
if(feof(fp)) break;
```

Is that a valid solution?

EDIT2: I have also solved it by putting a while loop to check if it has reached the end of the stream within the forloop:

```
int k;
char string[100];

for(k = 0; k < MAX_STATIONS; k++){
    while(!feof(fp)){
        fgets(string,100,fp);
        printf("%s", string);
        //if(feof(fp)) break;

    }
}
```

Comment: You sniped the code? But you didn't snipe the debugger...

Comment: @KerrekSB [Neither did he use the site search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to solve it is to test the input operation; using `feof()` is possible but not necessary, and requires care to get it right.  The way you show of using `feof()` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) on two counts; you don't test the I/O operation, and you introduce a loop that eats your entire input for `k == 0` leaving nothing for subsequent rows.

```
int k;
char string[100];
for (k = 0; k < MAX_STATIONS; k++)
{
    if (fgets(string, sizeof(string), fp) == 0)
        break;
    printf("%d: %s", k, string);
}
```

Or:

```
int k;
char string[100];
for (k = 0; k < MAX_STATIONS && fgets(string, sizeof(string), fp) == 0; k++)
    printf("%d: %s", k, string);
```

Note that `fgets()` retains the newline (unless the input line is too long to fit).

Comment: Does the method I have outlined work? Also, I'm wondering if you could outline what the 100 in fgets(string, 100, fp) does? I thought it was "read x amount of characters" but if I set it to 10, it will still read over 60 characters from my file.

EDIT: Read your link, quite helpful.So you're saying the way i've done it is good, but not optimal?

Comment: No; your alternative doesn't work — see my comments in the updated answer written while you were typing your comment/question. The 100 is the size of the string; it tells `fgets()` how much space there is in the string to store data.

Comment: Ahh okay, reading your link I understand what youre saying. If 100 is the size of the string, then how come if I set it to 10, it can still read over 60 chars?

Comment: It reads 10 characters at a time, but your printing prints the 10 characters at a time without any punctuation added.  Note how I added `%d:` to the format (and `k` to the arguments).  Try that with your `10` code and see `0:first ten 1:characters2: in the in3:put...` (if I got my counting correct).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it might be wise to read the manual page http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

If does return a value that may suggest that the file has ran out